# How to check the places variable not null?

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to use Angular Material autocomplete, but I have one error. The error is

```
: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

I think ,the problem is the `place[]` is null, when the filter is being applied. I dont know how to solve that.

The data is came into the PHP backend.

```
This is my TS file: https://pastebin.com/cAA3ycAA

And this is my template: https://pastebin.com/cxBnr5WU
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @bandy add check length of `place` if its is greater then `0` then apply filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy possibilities:
1) Check before returning if null, else return empty array:

```
return this.places ? this.places.filter(places => places.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)) : [];
```

2) set places by default as an empty array:

```
places:Place[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So, I try to check length, but it causedsome errors, and then I try to check to places not null, or not undefinied, but this is caused to same error on filter() like this:

[image]

```
 ngOnInit(
  ) { 
    this.getStudents();
    this.getPlaces();
    if(!this.places || this.places!==null)
    {
    this.filteredOptions = this.place.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code very well because i can see you used `places` in one statement then use `place` in another statement where you declared `this.place.valueChanges`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this part of your code.

{{option.name}}

First you need to replace option.name with **option** only.

Then in this piece of code.

private _filter(value: string): Place[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.places.filter(places => places.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}

A. Try replacing Place[] with string[].

B. Instead of .includes(filterValue) please try

return this.places.filter(places => places.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0)

Please let me know if it helps. Thanks :)